# Find Min value and max value of 9 previous rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

Please let me know how to calculate E column by provided formula in excel.
[image]

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [A] asc) AS id,A,B,C,0 as E into #temp from dbo.rawdata 
    order by id asc
    ------------------------- 

    update  #temp
    set E=((select max(h.B) from(select top (9) b.B from #temp b where b.id<#temp.id order by b.id asc)h) + (select min(l.C) from(select top (9) c.C from #temp c where c.id<#temp.id order by id asc)l))/2
    where id>10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but here's one method using an `OUTER APPLY`:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Order By A) As RN
    From    YourTable
)
Select  T1.A, T1.B, T1.C, T1.D, X.E
From    Cte T1
Outer Apply
(
    Select  (Max(T2.B) + Min(T2.C)) / 2 As E
    From    Cte T2
    Where   T2.RN >= (T1.RN - 9) 
    And     T2.RN < T1.RN
    And     T1.RN >= 10
) X
```

---

To `UPDATE` your table with these values, you can use the following:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Order By A) As RN
    From    YourTable
)
Update  T1
Set     E = X.E
From    Cte T1
Outer Apply
(
    Select  (Max(T2.B) + Min(T2.C)) / 2 As E
    From    Cte T2
    Where   T2.RN >= (T1.RN - 9) 
    And     T2.RN < T1.RN
    And     T1.RN >= 10
) X
```

Comment: @MahdiIBM Please specify that in the question.  Can you please elaborate more on what you're trying to update?

Comment: store (Max(T2.B) + Min(T2.C)) / 2 As E to my table

Comment: @MahdiIBM Updated